# How to write csv file without the brackets showing in the file itself

Tags: list, brackets

I'm writing data to a csv file, but somewhere I keep on getting the "(...)" in my file. How do I get rid of those?

The Snumber, Qnumber, Dnumber, Inumber, Pnumber are variables from a previous function that has some  basic calculations, of which I want to use the outcome of.

I know it's because of the list in  "entry_texts.append([Snumber, Qnumber, Dnumber, Inumber, Pnumber])"

```
##Buttons
entry_fields = (PC_label_var, cal, Shift, NameNumber1, Safetyentry, Qualityentry, Quality2entry, Deliveryentry, Delivery2entry, Inventoryentry,
                Productivityentry, Productivity2entry, Productivity3entry, Remarkstxt)

def save_file():
    # Ask the user for confirmation to save
    response_save = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno("Save Confirmation", "Wilt u opslaan?")
    
    if response_save:
        # User clicked "Yes," proceed with saving
        entry_texts = []
        for entry in entry_fields:
            if isinstance(entry, tk.StringVar):
                entry_texts.append(entry.get())
            elif isinstance(entry, tk.Text):
                entry_texts.append(entry.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
            else:
                entry_texts.append(entry.get())

        entry_texts.append([Snumber, Qnumber, Dnumber, Inumber, Pnumber])

        write_to_csv(entry_texts)

        # Ask the user if they want to shut down the application
        response_shutdown = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno("Shutdown Confirmation", "Wilt u het programma afsluiten?")
        if response_shutdown:
            root.destroy()  # Close the main application window
    else:
        # User clicked "No" or closed the dialog, don't save the data
        print("Data not saved")
```

I tried various ways of recreating that list with different brackets, but to no avail

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Keep in mind to trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).